# Bug when I try to access memory from a list of a struct: " Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Tags: c++, list, header, segmentation-fault

EDITED: Hello everyone! I have being having problems with this particular code, when I want to access to the data in `lista->arch->nombreArchivo` from main. The program crashes, when I debuged it I found out that the problem is a "segmentation fault"-type of error. I think I lack an allocation but I don't know where.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

#include "Sistema.h"
#include "Archivo.h"
#include "Directorio.h"
#include "ListaArchivos.h"
#include "Constantes.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    /* VARIABLES */
    Cadena c_DIR=(char *)"DIR";
    Cadena c_CREATEFILE=(char *)"CREATEFILE";
    Cadena c_DELETE=(char *)"DELETE";
    Cadena c_ATTRIB=(char *)"ATTRIB";
    Cadena c_IF=(char *)"IF";
    Cadena c_DF=(char *)"DF";
    Cadena c_TYPE=(char *)"TYPE";
    Cadena c_CREARSISTEMA=(char *)"CREARSISTEMA";
    Cadena c_DESTRUIRSISTEMA=(char *)"DESTRUIRSISTEMA";
    Cadena c_EXIT=(char *)"EXIT";
    Cadena Segmento;
    Cadena comando;
    Cadena parametro1;
    Cadena parametro2;
    bool seguir;
    int contador=0;
    char frase[50];
    Archivo *arch; /here i declare arch
    ListaArchivos *lista; //here i declare lista

    /* ESTRUCTURA DE REPETICION PARA QUE EFECTUE EL COMANDO PEDIDO HASTA QUE EL BOOL SALIR SEA FALSO, MEDIANTE EL COMANDO EXIT */
    do{
    cout <<"> ";

    /* ALGORITMO PARA DIVIDIR LA FRASE EN TOKENS */
    fgets(frase,50,stdin);
    Segmento=strtok(frase," ");
    while(Segmento!=NULL){
             if( contador == 0 ){
                 comando=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL COMANDO */
             }
             if ( contador == 1 ){
                  parametro1=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL PRIMER PARAMETRO */
             }
             if( contador == 2 ){
                 parametro2=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL SEGUNDO PARAMETRO */
             }
             Segmento=strtok(NULL, " ");
             contador++;
    }

    /* SELECCIONA EL COMANDO INDICADO, COMPARANDO LA CADENA COMANDO CON LAS DIFERENTES CADENAS */
    if (strcmp(comando,c_DIR)== 0){
        cout <<"Uso comando DIR"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    else{
        if (strcmp(comando,c_CREATEFILE)== 0){

            *lista=crearListaArchivos(); //CREATE LIST OF ARCH.


            cout<<"LISTA CREted, SU DIRECCION ES "<< &lista<<endl;

            *arch=crearArchivo(parametro1); //CREATE ARCH
            cout<<"ARCHIVO CREAted, SU DIRECCION ES"<<&arch<<" SU NOMBRE ES: "<<(*arch)->nombreArchivo<<endl;

            insertarArchivoListaArchivos(*lista,*arch); //INSERTS ARCH IN LIST OF ARCHS but Im not certain that it actually inserts it. 

            cout <<" THE ARCHIVO IN lista es named ..."<<(*lista)->arch->nombreArchivo<<endl<<endl; //here it crashes
        }
/* ....
......
......
.....*/
    return 0;
}
```

**header of ARCHIVO**

```
struct _archivo{  //aca declaro la estructura de un archivo
    Cadena nombreArchivo;
    Cadena Atributos;
    Cadena Contenido;
    _archivo *Siguiente;
    _archivo *Anterior;
};
typedef _archivo* Archivo;

/*
 * Crea e inicializa un archivo con nombre 'nombreArchivo'
 */
Archivo crearArchivo(Cadena nombreArchivo){

    Archivo *nuevoArchivo=new Archivo; //inicializo
    (*nuevoArchivo)=new _archivo;
    // lo inicializo

 //   (*nuevoArchivo)->Atributos=(char* )"Lectura/Escritura";
 //   (*nuevoArchivo)->Contenido=NULL;
    (*nuevoArchivo)->nombreArchivo=nombreArchivo;
    (*nuevoArchivo)->Siguiente=NULL;
    (*nuevoArchivo)->Anterior=NULL;
    return *nuevoArchivo; //devuelvo el archivo inizializado
}
```

**header of list listaArchivo**

```
struct _listaArchivos{ //defino la estructura _listaArchivos, que sera una lista de nodos de tipo Archivo, definidos en el header Archivo.h
    Archivo arch;
};
typedef _listaArchivos* ListaArchivos;

/*
 * creates initializes and return a new lista of archivo.
 */
/*
ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
           ListaArchivos *lista; //cuando lo corro al programa, con el debugger, me manda a esta funcion.
            lista=new ListaArchivos;

        *lista=new _listaArchivos;

       (*lista)->arch=NULL;

       return *lista;}*/

ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
     ListaArchivos *lista = new ListaArchivos;
     (*lista) = new _listaArchivos;
     (*lista)->arch=NULL;
     return *lista;
}
/*
 * Inserta el archivo 'archivo' en la lista 'lista'.
 */
void insertarArchivoListaArchivos(ListaArchivos &lista, Archivo archivo){
    Archivo *nuevoArchivo;
    nuevoArchivo=new Archivo;
    *nuevoArchivo=archivo;
    if (lista==NULL){
        lista->arch=*nuevoArchivo;
        lista->arch->Anterior=NULL;
        lista->arch->Siguiente=NULL;
    }/*falta terminar, no interesa*/
}
```

If you please could give me some idea of how I can fix this bug, Id really thanked you. 
Thanks very much!

Comment: And why are you using `cout` but not `cin`?

Comment: And when you run the program in a debugger, where does it crash? What's the backtrace?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Cadena is a char* defined in other header. I use cout, and for in I use fgets at the top of the do while. 
The program crashes when I try to access the information in lista, in main

Comment: You have heard of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)? If not then you do now. And *don't use `char*` for character literals*, use either `const char*` or `char[]`.

Comment: I know there's more efficients ways, the thing is this is a problem that was given to me this way in University, and I cannot change the headers or the definitions. Thanks very much for the tip though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `crearArchivo` and `crearListaArchivos` functions are just... wrong!

As the `Archivo` and `ListaArchivos`types already are pointers, there's no need to use an extra level of indirection that you allocate (and can not free, thereby creating a memory leak).

For example, the `crearListaArchivos` function could be rewritten like

```
ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
     ListaArchivos lista = new _listaArchivos;
     lista->arch=NULL;
     return lista;
}
```

Do similar for `crearArchivo`.

---

As for the crash, see these lines:

```
ListaArchivos *lista;

...

*lista=crearListaArchivos();
```

When you declare a local variable, it's value is indeterminate, so accessing it before its initialized leads to undefined behavior. Here you have a pointer (`lista`) which is uninitialize, i.e. does not point anywhere, and then you use `*lista` to dereference that uninitialized pointer which leads to undefined behavior and the crash.

What you first of all need to do is remove all extra indirections! The `ListaArchivos` type already is a pointer, no need to make it a pointer to a pointer! So this will be what you want:

```
ListaArchivos lista;

...

lista=crearListaArchivos();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joachim, that helped a lot! Wish I could vote the question, but I cannot just yet

Comment: I made those changes in main to lista, do I have to make the same with arch in main?

Comment: Ok, the problem now.. The program is still crushing when I want to access the data in lista->arch->nombreArchivo; in main. Why is that? I want to know what archivo I added to the list lista